# how can I invoke setjmp on ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, glibc

I'm reading expert c, and got through setjump and longjump section, so want make the code running on my ubuntu 11.10, but when I include setjump.h, the gcc compiler complain that it can't find the header file, I find there is not a setjump.h in the /user/include/ directory.
So what should I do? Can you give me some suggestions?

Comment: It's `/usr`, not `/user`. The problem with your header file name is very similar :) Unix hates vowels! You should learn to hate them, too ;)

Comment: not to be picky but 'u' is a vowel :)

Comment: oh, I think I was confused by the setjump vs setjmp , user vs usr. thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `setjmp(3)` man page:

> ```
> SYNOPSIS
>        #include <setjmp.h>
> ```